# Are annotations must to Serailaize the java object via JaxB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Sometimes it serializes without annotations in xml and the other times it doesnt?Someone please enlighten me regarding the necessity of Annotations.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Test {


    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    private int age;
    private String name;
    private Cat cat;

    public Test()
    {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }


    public Cat getCat() {
        return cat;
    }

    public void setCat(Cat cat) {
        this.cat = cat;
    }
}


 class Cat
{
   private String name="catttttttttttttttt";

public Cat()
{

}
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

In the above code,it works fine,but sometimes if dont add @XMLElement above the getCat(),it doesnt serialize.

Comment: no it is not. but how do you serialize? show the code.

Comment: Thanks.I learned its not required to use annoataions every time.Please look at my new comment.

Answer (score 0):

I googled through some sites and got the best explanation here:

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Its not required to put annotations and it depends completely on @XmlAccessorType.
Thanq

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        JAXBContext contextObj = JAXBContext.newInstance(Test.class);

        Marshaller marshallerObj = contextObj.createMarshaller();
        marshallerObj.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        Test test = new Test();test.setAge(25);test.setName("Sriharsha");test.setCat(new Cat());

        marshallerObj.marshal(test, new FileOutputStream("/home/pankaj/Downloads/Emp.xml"));
        System.out.println();



    }
}
```